# regular expression match if groups same

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to match iff two capture groups are the same. I could manually check after the match, but I'm wondering if there is a way I can do this in the expression itself.

My expression is `(\d+)\/(\d+)`, so I only want to accept strings where the two numbers are equal. Is there a nice way to check this in the regular expression, or do I have to manually check groups after?

EDIT: This was marked a duplicate but the supposed duplicate question is not related and does not in any way answer my question...

Comment: Use `r'\b(\d+)/\1\b'` (or `r'^(\d+)/\1$` if the whole input is in `num/num` format).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What does `r` do?

Comment: @CinCout: Defines a raw string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this one in python : `\b(\d+)\/+\1\b`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EmCRxk/2)

**This is the same usecase as checking for doubled words**

When editing text, doubled words such as "the the" easily creep in. Using the regex `\b(\w+)\s+\1\b` in your text editor, you can easily find them. To delete the second word, simply type in `\1` as the replacement text and click the Replace button.

[Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't have any other capture groups, based on that:

```
\b(\d+)\/(\1)\b
```

---

[image]

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ADbWeZ/3)

Comment: Care to comment the downvote?

Comment: wasnt my downvote, but i imagine lack of explanation?

Comment: Same for me, I've added an answer, almost the same as Wiktor, again ;), but with a example on regex101 that took me the 2 more minutes and it was immediatly downvoted without any explication/comment. It's ridiculous, I deleted it.

Comment: Undelete my answer with more information. Maybe it'll help @chris.

Comment: @chris https://ideone.com/mktlxJ

Comment: I don't know if this deserves a new question, but what should one do when trying to match strings that must have the ```(\d+)\/(\d+)``` but when the first number should be different from the second?